# Site displays completely different in IE than Chrome and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Here is my site: http://www.playerspace.com

open it in firefox its fine
open it in chrome its fine
open it in IE its completely screwed up.

Any ideas? I can understand some minor differences but what the heck is going on here?

Comment: for me it looks fine on ie7-8-9-10. hmm that's weird behavior i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some odd reason this occurred when i switched from application.cfm to application.cfc

I don't know why, but returning to .cfm fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

what version of internet explorer are you using ? and are you using any html 5 in your script because i dont think that internet explorer supports this (as of yet)

Answer (score 0):

Here is very good solution for this common IE problem [IE6-7-8-9.FIX](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), it helped me

Comment: this did not seem to have any effect